# How To Upgrade Snow Leopard to Lion (not Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I couldn't find Mac OS X Lion in the App Store. Can I go from Snow Leopard to Lion without migrating to Mountain Lion?

Many programs are now dropping support for Snow Leopard (newer XCode, newer fortran compilers, etc.), but I don't want Mountain Lion. Mountain Lion still lacks support for some software that I like (ex. Little Snitch).

What are my (legal) options?

Comment: Have you previously purchased Lion from the MAS?

Comment: I do a quick search with Google and find nothing… But be carefull with upgrade to Lion, I try it and after 3 days, I downgrade to Snow Leopard !

Comment: @SamuelE.Giddins no

Answer (score 1):

Call Apple, 1-800-My-Apple and order Lion over the phone.

This is the only way to get it now. Apple will email you a code you use on the App store to download it.

BTW - Little Snitch is Mountain Lion compatible now.  I highly recommend upgrading to Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Or visit a nearby Apple Store after making an appointment for the Genius desk.

A friend of mine was offered to upgrade his machine - which is not able to run Mountain Lion - from 10.6 to 10.7 for free at the Genius desk in Amsterdam.